# Appium+Python. Не работает метод click() по найденному элементу на Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, click, appium

В моем тесте присутствует поиск кнопки (регистрация), нажатие на нее и работа со следующим экраном (формой регистрации).
Кнопка находится. Об этом свидетельствует соответствующий print, который выводит текст с этой кнопки. Но register_button.click() не работает. Как  следствие, выводится эксепшн о том, что не нашелся элемент, который есть на следующем экране.

На телефоне тоже вижу, что перехода не происходит.
В логах аппиума ничего подозрительного нет: примерно то же самое, что и в консоли.
На 8 версии андроида кнопка нажимается и тест проходит полностью.

```
import unittest, time, os
import appium
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class UTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = {
        "unicodeKeyboard": "true",
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "6.0.1",
        "deviceName": "4c1a02ab7d14",
        "udid": "4c1a02ab7d14",
        "appPackage": "*****",
        "appActivity": "*****.presentation.ui.splash.SplashActivity",
        "app": "C:\\Users\\Viktoriya\\Downloads\\*****.apk"
        }

    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

def test_signin(self):

    # Start screen
    time.sleep(5)

    # register_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Зарегистрироваться']")
    register_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('*****:id/btn_register')
    if register_button.is_displayed():
        print ("Button found "+register_button.text)
        register_button.click()
    else:
        print ("Button not found")


    time.sleep(5)

    # Sign up form
    user_fullname = self.driver.find_element_by_id('*****:id/full_name_edit')
    if user_fullname.is_displayed():
        print("Name found")
        user_fullname.send_keys('Tester');
    else:
        print("Name not found")
(...)
```

---

```
D:\test\Frame>python -m unittest sign_up.py
Button found Зарегистрироваться
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_signin (sign_up.UTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\Frame\sign_up.py", line 47, in test_signin
    user_fullname = self.driver.find_element_by_id('app.allabout.me:id/full_name_edit')
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 351, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
    super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Viktoriya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 44.188s

FAILED (errors=1)
```